# turn Y axis upside down

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a simple bar chart in D3, but the the bars are being created from top to bottom, instead of bottom to top. Below is the xScale, yScale and bar generation code:

```
var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, data.length])
  .range([0, 240]);

var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 240]);

var bar = canvas.append('g')
  .attr("id", "bar-group")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,20)")
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("height", function(d, i) {
    return yscale(d);
  })
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("x", function(i) {
    return yscale(i);
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .style("fill", function(i) {
    return colors(i);
  });
```

Tried to swap yScale ranges but no success. [Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9up3vv1h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SVG coordinates system, the origin (0,0) is at the *top* left corner, not the bottom left corner.

Besides that, your SVG has only 150px heigh. Thus, change your scale:

```
var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 150]);
```

And the math of your bars:

```
.attr("height", function(d, i) {
    return yscale(d);
})
.attr("y", function(d){
    return 150 - yscale(d)
})
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bga2q72f/

PS: don't use the *same* scale for the x and y positions. It's quite confusing.